# Find next and previous keys in js array

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, underscore.js

I have an array

`var arr = ["1", "3", "2", "4"];`

I need a function that returns the next or the previous array key based on a given key value:

```
function closestTo(arr, key, direction) { 
 // do stuff here and return the next or previous id
}
```

So to find next of 4, I call the function; `closestTo(arr, 4, 'next' )` this should return `1`

And `closestTo(arr, 4, 'prev' )` should return `2`

Any ideas of this could also achieved with [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)?

Comment: For 1 and "prev" it has to be ...? And if the key isn't found?

Comment: it has to be 4 :) .. It is like a loop; so always returns something except when the supplied key is not found; inthis case it returns null or false.. ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something [like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/n4ldKIg1ekm2IJIKlT6y)?

```
function closestTo(arr, key, direction) {
    var offset_index = (direction === 'prev') ? -1 : 1;

    // Convert to integers
    var intarr = arr.map(function(x) {
        return parseInt(x, 10);
    });

    return intarr[(intarr.length + intarr.indexOf(key) + offset_index) % intarr.length];
}
```

Comment: `closestTo([1,2,3],1,'prev')` will show `undefined`. OP wants `3` to be the output.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer, but change (direction == 'prev') to ===
and if you are using strings like the OP posted this will not work for those string values.

Answer (score 3):

I have wrote script for you:)
http://jsfiddle.net/maxim_mazurok/6s7z6zwt/
But array should be like `var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];` if you want to call function with number as a second param.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function closestTo(arr, key, direction) {
    var last = arr.length - 1;
    var first = 0;
    var keyIndex = arr.indexOf(key);
    switch (direction) {
        case ('next'):
            if (keyIndex != last) {
                return arr[keyIndex + 1];
            } else {
                return arr[first];
            }
            break;
        case ('prev'):
            if (keyIndex != first) {
                return arr[keyIndex - 1];
            } else {
                return arr[last];
            }
    }
}
alert(closestTo(arr, 4, 'next' ));
alert(closestTo(arr, 4, 'prev' ));
```

Comment: When using switch should always include default case. Also can reach last with index -1 no reason to do a array length -1

Comment: @Geohut well.. actually not, because we aren't know the context. It is very possible, that `direction` was checked before in the code, so there is no other possible value (only `'next'` and `'prev'`). But generally, I will agree with you. In production every double-check matter :)

Comment: yeah I mean you are right but best practices wise and for error checking it's good to do.

Answer (score 1):

You only need pure JavaScript for this:

```
function closestTo(arr, key, direction) {
    var keyIndex = arr.indexOf(key),
        indexToReturn;

    if (direction === 'prev') {
        indexToReturn = keyIndex > 0 ? keyIndex - 1 : arr.length -1;
    } else if (direction === 'next') {
        indexToReturn = keyIndex < arr.length - 1 ? keyIndex + 1 : 0;
    }

    return arr[indexToReturn];
}
```